# How do I set the right date from an external JSON file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 and I have a question about date formatting and displaying. You can find my example below.

```
d3.json('jsonData.json', function(data) {

nv.addGraph(function() {    
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 90})
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d].x || 0;
            return dx ? d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%e %X')(new Date(dx)) : '';
        });

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f')(d));

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

    //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    //nv.utils.windowResize(function() { d3.select('#chart1 svg').call(chart) });

        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

    return chart;
  });
});
```

The JSON file jsonData is built like this :

```
    [{ 
       "key":"Consumption", 
       "values":[ [2012-06-27 00:00:00 , 153580] , [2012-06-27 02:00:00 , 153590] , [...] , [...] , ... , [...] ]
    }]
```

with a date format like this: "Year-month-day hour:minutes:seconds"

The problem is that I can't display anyhing... I know something is missing to display that chart with the consumption on the Y axis and the date on the X axis but I can't find what...

I have tried many of ways to do it, inspired from som examples from nvd3.org, but nothing is working :/

Thanks for your answers!

-----------------------------------------------  EDIT  -------------------------------------

Thanks Andrew and George, I solved my problem thanks to the examples given on nvd3.org.

I used a PHP script to correctly format my date in a timestamp (with milliseconds) and re-used the example "linePlusBarChart".

After all, my code and my JSON file look like this :

```
d3.json('jsonData.json', function(data) {

data.map(function(series) {
series.values = series.values.map(function(d) { return {x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
return series;
});

nv.addGraph(function() {    
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 90})
        .x(function(d,i) { return i })
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
            var dx = data[0].values[d] && data[0].values[d].x || 0;
            return dx ? d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(dx)) : '';
        });

    chart.yAxis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

    return chart;
   });
});
```

And the JSON file:

```
    [{
      "key":"Consommation", 
      "values":[[1340755200000 , 153580] , [1340762400000 , 153590] , 
                [1340769600000 , 153610] , [1340776800000 , 153650] , 
                [1340784000000 , 153680] , [1340791200000 , 153720] , 
                [1340798400000 , 153780] , [1340805600000 , 153830] , 
                [1340812800000 , 153880] , [1340820000000 , 153900] , 
                [1340827200000 , 153920] , [1340834400000 , 153930] , 
                [1343347200000 , 153940] 
               ]
     }]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [time parsing functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse) built into D3.

For a working example, take a look at how the parseDate var is declared and then used in [this chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955)

Comment: Thanks! I finally found the answer! (see EDIT part)

Answer (score 0):

Consider use long millseconds to pass parameters in JSON.